# Implement passportjs and angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, passport.js

Look, i've made a mean stack app with register/login using passportjs, and it was fine, when i change to angular2(the other was on angularjs) i've made the backend side and i think it works but i dont know how to test it on the fronted side, i know it has to be something with the url in the `<a href="">` but when i put the route that passport gives me, example: `/auth/facebook`, my aplication does nothing... well it does something, send me to the homepage :c
here is my code so far on the backend side

```
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const session          = require('express-session');
const secret           = require('../config/database')
const user             = require('../models/user')

module.exports = function(app, passport){
      app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());
        app.use(session({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { secure: false }
      }));

      passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      token = jwt.sign({email: user.email}, secret, {expiresIn : '24h'});
      done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    });
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: '350645212059140',
        clientSecret: '8a990aec6db37cc3535f4223c235c427',
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:4200/auth/facebook/callback",
        profileFields: ['id','displayName','email']
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile);
        // User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
        //   if (err) { return done(err); }
        //   done(null, user);
        // });
        done(null, profile)
      }
    ));
    app.get('/auth/facebook',passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback' , passport.authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect: '/login'}), function(res, res){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }else{
        res.send('wi')
      }
    })
  return passport;
}
```

my question is, how can i implement this on the fronted side, remember angular 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code for this.

Step 1: When you are submitting your form using ngSubmit call a function for instance passportLogin().

Step 2: Now in your component use this function and do an HTTP post request to your node js(express js) URL, for example, auth/login.

Step 3: In the server side write a routing

```
var express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router();
module.exports = function(passport){
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect: '/auth/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
    }));
}
```